# Button with an icon and centered text

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, resize

I am working on a button component with an icon and text.

The icon is positioned on the left side of the button, and the text is centered within the button.
If the text cannot fit inside the button, it shouldn't wrap to a new line, but can be truncated.
The key condition for truncating the text is that the distance from the text to the edge of the button should be the same as the distance of the icon from the edge of the button.
So you can't add equal inline paddings to the button.

If the text is not truncated, it is centered within the button.
However, as soon as it starts overlapping the icon or doesn't fit inside the button, the text gets truncated.

In other words, in the normal state, the icon is positioned as is, but when there isn't enough space for the text, the icon pushes the text until it's truncated.

[Visual example of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVZlw.png)

I have tried to achieve this with CSS, but failed.
I ended up adding a ResizeObserver to each button, which calculates whether there is enough space for the text.
If there isn't enough space, different styles are applied to the icon.

My solution with ResizeObserver, try to resize the window
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/BoringChip/pen/BaGXwZO)

```
const CLASS_TEXT = `button__text`;
const CLASS_NO_FREE_SPACE = `button_no-free-space`;
const FREE_SPACE_SIZE = 70;

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`.${CLASS_ROOT}`);

const handleButtonResize = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const { target } = entry;
    const text = target.querySelector(`.${CLASS_TEXT}`);
    const { width: widthButton } = entry.contentRect;

    if (!(text instanceof HTMLElement)) {
      return;
    }

    const widthText = text.offsetWidth;
    const freeSpaceLeft = (widthButton - widthText) / 2;
    const noFreeSpace = freeSpaceLeft <= FREE_SPACE_SIZE;

    target.classList.toggle(CLASS_NO_FREE_SPACE, noFreeSpace);
  });
};

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(handleButtonResize);

[...buttons].forEach((button) => {
  resizeObserver.observe(button);
});
```

**My question is:**
Is it possible to achieve the same effect using pure CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the icons are always the same width (`2em`), we can use an `::after` pseudo-element as a "buffer" for the right-side space balance.

Have the `.button__icon` be in the flex layout flow. This will be crucial in "pushing" our other elements. Give it `margin-right` to balance the left padding of the button.

Create an `::after` pseudo element that has `flex-basis: calc(2em + 20px)`. The `2em` for the `.button__icon`'s width plus `20px` for the `.button__icon`'s `margin-right`. This balances out the left and right space equally when `.button__text` is short.

Apply `justify-content: space-between` to the parent to aid in balancing out `.button__icon`, `.button__text` and `::after` when `.button__text` is short.

Add `flex-shrink: 999`, a huge shrink factor, so that the layout engine prioritizes the shrinking of the `::after` element when the `.button__text` is longer.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.button::after {
  flex: 0 999 calc(2em + 20px);
  content: "";
}

.button__icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.button__text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"/>

<div class="grid">
  <button class="button">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-heart fa-2xl button__icon"></i>
   
    <span class="button__text">
      Long text that should be truncated
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="button">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up fa-2xl button__icon"></i>
   
    <span class="button__text">
      Medium length
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="button">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-2xl button__icon"></i>
   
    <span class="button__text">
      Short
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

To avoid `.button__text` shrinking early, we could consider having the `::after` *grow* **to** `calc(2em + 20px)`:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.button::after {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: calc(2em + 20px);
  content: "";
}

.button__icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.button__text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"/>

<div class="grid">
  <button class="button">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-heart fa-2xl button__icon"></i>
   
    <span class="button__text">
      Long text that should be truncated
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="button">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up fa-2xl button__icon"></i>
   
    <span class="button__text">
      Medium length
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="button">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-2xl button__icon"></i>
   
    <span class="button__text">
      Short
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but in your solution, the long text starts to truncate too early. There is plenty of space on the right side of the button [Long text should be truncated only when it reaches the right side if the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE6qW.png)

Comment: Updated with an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, this version of the solution works perfectly!